# Simulate Dataset in R

Tags: r, simulation

How can I simulate  100 times the following dataset of equal size using R and the estimates from the  summary output???

```
  rating officer
1     76       1
2     65       1
3     85       1
4     74       1
5     59       2
6     75       2
7     81       2
8     67       2

> > fit5=lmer(rating~(1|officer),data=rat, REML=FALSE)
> summary(fit5)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood 
Formula: rating ~ (1 | officer) 
   Data: rat 
   AIC  BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 62.06 62.3 -28.03    56.06   52.07
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 officer  (Intercept)  0.000   0.0000  
 Residual             64.688   8.0429  
Number of obs: 8, groups: officer, 2

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   72.750      2.844   25.58
```

Comment: have you read the help page for `simulate.merMod()` in lme4 package?

Answer (score 2):

If by simulate, you mean resample, something like this should do it:

```
replicate(100,
          summary(lmer(rating~(1|officer), 
                       data=rat[sample(1:nrow(rat),nrow(rat),TRUE)),],
                       REML=FALSE)))
```